# ¿La propiedad 'id' no existe en el tipo 'User'?

Tags: nodejs, express, id

estoy aprendiendo a programar en **NodeJS** y estaba creando una aplicación de crear notas con **mongoodb** siguiendo un tutorial, el problema es que al llegar a la parte donde liga las notas a un ID de usuario este no me lo reconoce como una propiedad de mi "user" y solo marca en VS code el mensaje **"La propiedad 'id' no existe en el tipo 'User'"** por lo que no puedo crear notas para cada usuario registrado. No me marca ningún error y de hecho se ejecuta correctamente, pero en el código me marca ese detalle.

[image: Mensaje que muestra en VS code]

Este es el código de cuando se crea la nota:

```
const NewNote = new Note({ title, description });
NewNote.user = req.user.id; //Este id es el que me marca como inexistente
await NewNote.save();
req.flash('success_msg', 'Nota agregada correctamente'); 
res.redirect('/notes');
```

Este es mi código del Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

 const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required:true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});

UserSchema.methods.encryptPassword = async (password) => { 
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hash(password, salt); 
    return hash;
};

UserSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (password) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Y estas son mis variables globales:

```
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
});
```

He buscado bastante rato alguna solución o del porque, pero no encuentro nada, si alguien sabe me ayudara mucho. Saludos

Comment: Veo que usas Typescript, habría que ver qué tipo le estás asignando a `req.user`.

Answer (score 0):

intenta de esta manera

```
NewNote.user = req.user._id;
```

De forma predeterminada, Mongoose agrega una propiedad _id a los esquemas.

[get _id with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42188449/11283620)

Comment: Ya lo intente de esa forma pero sigue sin reconocerlo, gracias.

Comment: entonces si te marca como indefinido viene desde el controlador/metodo en el cual esta, ya que no lo esta pasando.  ponele un console.log(req.user) mas arriba